# Issue running sql script through SQLCMD utility

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a script which im running through sql command utility and in one varchar field im inserting this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(body).css(''margin'',''400px'')
})
</script>
```

and it gives me this

```
'document' scripting variable not defined.
'body' scripting variable not defined.
```

error. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLCMD` uses the form `$(...)` to do variable substitution at run-time.

You can switch variable substitution off with the `-x` option.

```
SQLCMD -x <the rest of your command string>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) for more details